# How can I iterate through multiple folders, read only certain CSV folders into R, and write a corrected CSV back into each respective folder?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I have 20 or so folders in a directory that I need to iterate through, read only certain CSV files into R, and write them into the original folder with a different name, but I am having trouble doing so. After running the code below, there are no data frames read into R, and no new CSV files are written to my folders. How can I fix this?

Below is what I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

parent_directory <- 'C:\\path\\to\\directory\\with\\the\\multiple\\folders'

folders <- list.dirs(parent_directory, recursive = FALSE)

for (folder in folders) {
  # Opening each CSV file in each folder ending with "NAMES.csv"
  csv_files <- list.files(folder, pattern = "NAMES\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
  
  for (csv_file in csv_files) {
    #the 'sep = ";"' argument is necessary because the files need to be fitted into distinct columns
    df <- read.csv(csv_file, sep = ";") 
    write.csv(df, "NAMES_CORRECTED.csv")
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the folder path in the `write.csv` command -  right now it is writing to your working directory - try something like `write.csv(df, paste0(folder, "/NAMES_CORRECTED.csv")) ` - as or why no frames are being read into R, not sure - the code worked with sample file structures for me